# &nbsp; is displaying instead of space in my html template in angular 6

Tags: html, angular6

I'm getting the json response and displaying in my html page like below.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemData.additionalTechnicalData | keyvalue">
  <td class="smallboldblack" align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowarp">{{item.key}}:</td>
  <td class="small" valign="top" align="left">{{item.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

When the {{item.value}} is space(" ") only then it is displaying as [image]  in my template.

Help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Lets look at the json data. share it

Comment: also try removing keyvalue pipe and check.

Comment: check this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4ctul).. I've done the same thing except pipe...pipe may be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Booth `&#160;` and `&nbsp;` should write out a space for example if i type `"test&#160;test&nbsp;test"` it will output this "test test test"